# Is adding objects in loop cheaper than add_all with long list?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating test `Flask-SQLAlchemy` model instances in this example:

```py
instances= [
    CustomModel(id="...", label="...", ...),
    CustomModel(id="...", label="...", ...),
    CustomModel(id="...", label="...", ...),
    CustomModel(id="...", label="...", ...),
    CustomModel(id="...", label="...", ...),
    ...
]
db.session.add_all(instances)
```

But I've found another approach in our legacy code base which has done this:

```py
instances_data = [
    {
        "id": "...",
        "label": "...",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "...",
        "label": "...",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "...",
        "label": "...",
        ...
    },
    ...
]

for data in instances_data:
    obj = CustomModel(**data)
    db.session.add(obj)
```

The second one does more separate db insertions which I don't like. On the other hand it only creates one object at a time so I guess this can be a time/cost trade-off scenario.

So I started to wonder whether there's indeed any real difference in time and cost for a theoretically huge amount of instances.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to benchmark it.

Comment: The usual assumption is that database queries are expensive, so you try to minimize the number.

Comment: The difference is probably negligible: adding items to a session doesn't hit the database.  But as Barmar says, if you want to know for sure, measure.

Comment: You have the code.  You have the database.  Why are you asking Stack Overflow?  Just try both of them.  I suspect the difference is negligible.

Comment: @FrankYellin Well I thought maybe there is some angle I did not think of so I always ask. But yes, I'll try to benchmark for sure.